# How do determine which OS version to use?

Tags: installation, software-recommendation

I'm not sure if I should get a 64 or 32 bit OS even though I have a 64 bit computer.

I have an an HP Pavilion Phenom 4 core with 8 gigs of ram.

Is this a good candidate for Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This machine should be able to run 64-bit perfectly.

Given that you have 8 GB RAM, the benefits of 64-bit (faster performance for multimedia software) outweigh the major disadvantage (increased RAM usage).